# How to build query in laravel to find out near by hotels or hospitals

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am running this query in phpmyadmin and it is working but i dont know how to write it in laravel

```
select * from(SELECT *, SQRT(POW(69.1 * (`latitude` - $current_Lat), 2) + POW(69.1 * (73.8432228 - $current_long) * COS(`latitude` / 57.3), 2)) AS distance FROM location_details ORDER BY distance ASC ) as NEAR_BY_TABLE limit 0,1;
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: $NearBy = DB::table('location_details')
                ->select('Id')
                ->where(SQRT(POW(69.1 * ('latitude' - $current_latitude), 2) + POW(69.1 * (73.8432228 - $current_latitude) * COS('latitude' / 57.3), 2)))
                ->get();

Answer (score 1):

You have to build it with the query builder.

```
DB::table('location_details')
    ->select('*')
    ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT *, SQRT(POW(69.1 * (`latitude` - '.$current_Lat.'), 2) + POW(69.1 * (73.8432228 - '.$current_long.') * COS(`latitude` / 57.3), 2)) AS distance FROM location_details ORDER BY distance ASC ) as NEAR_BY_TABLE'))
    ->take(1)
    ->get()
;
```

Should work. Not tested. Please take a look at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries or http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries

But you shouldn't pass the variables like in my example if it's user input.